# how to make queue of type struct in golang

Tags: go, queue

````
type top struct {
    node *tree
    hd   int
}

func (t *bt) topview() {
    if t.root == nil {
        return
    }
    qu := list.New()
    qu.PushBack(top{t.root, 0})
    sample := qu.Front()
    fmt.Println(sample.hd)```
````

fails with error sample.hd undefined (type *list.Element has no field or method hd)

Comment: While you can implement a queue using a list a slice may be more appropriate - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21328187/11810946) for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need

```
fmt.Println(sample.Value.(top).hd)
```

Your value "sample" is a [`list.Element`](https://golang.org/pkg/container/list/#Element), which is a struct containing some hidden fields related to the list structure, as well as a field `Value`, which is the actual data that you stored in it.  `Value` is of type `interface{}`, so you need to do a [type assertion](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15) to use your struct fields.

Comment: for qu != nil {
  sample := qu.Front()
  for key := range topview {
   if key != sample.Value.(top).hd {
    topview[sample.Value.(top).hd] = sample.Value.(top).node
   }
  }
  if sample.Value.(top).node.left != nil {
   qu.PushBack(top{sample.Value.(top).node.left, sample.Value.(top).hd - 1})
  }
  if sample.Value.(top).node.right != nil {
   qu.PushBack(top{sample.Value.(top).node.right, sample.Value.(top).hd + 1})
  }
  qu.Remove(qu.Front())
 }
fails with this error

Comment: panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x10 pc=0x109e13d]